# Need to find arrays inside a container array which contains a specific text in its certain position in apps script (preferred) or java script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

****I have an array containing other arrays which is as below, my purpose is to find the arrays in it which are containing the string Type 4 Sheets at their 3rd position inside them. Generally speaking, it will be really great if I can get only those arrays inside the bigger array which contains a specific string at nth position****

```
[[sheets at upper, intermediate and lower, Type 4 Sheets, Sheets, 8.0, 1.5, 5.0, , 3.0, Exact Sized Material # 1],
 [sheets at  back , Type 4 Sheets, Sheets, 8.0, 1.0, 2.5, , 1.0, Exact Sized Material # 2], 
[dfsdfdsfsd, Type 2 Gola, Gola, 5.0, 1.5, 2.5, , 2.0, Exact Sized Material # 3],
 [sheets at vertical divider, Type 1 Gola, Gola, , 1.5, 2.5, , 1.0, Exact Sized Material # 4], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.0, , 2.5, , 4.0, Exact Sized Material # 5], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 8.0, , , , 12.0, Exact Sized Material # 6], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 8.0, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 7], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.5, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 8], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 1.5, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 9], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.5, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 10], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.5, , , , 4.0, Exact Sized Material # 11], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.0, , , , 32.0, Exact Sized Material # 12], 
[sheets at shutters,  , , 2.5, , , , 32.0, Exact Sized Material # 13]]
```

Comment: Did you check forEach structures? Are you looking for something like `array.forEach(function(a) { if (a[2] =="Type 4 Sheets") results.push(a) });` ? Results should have all arrays that contains the given string in the 3rd. position.

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps

```
arr.filter(x => x[positionToCheck] === stringToCheck)
```

based on comments here is transpiled version

```
arr.filter(function (x) {
  return x[positionToCheck] === stringToCheck;
});
```

Comment: You'll need to rewrite the arrow functions as standard JS 1.6, as Google Apps Script has only some support for newer JS features. (`Array#filter` is supported)

Comment: I tried    var filtered = exactSizedMaterialsData.filter(x => x[3] === "Type 4 Sheets");  according to the provided solution but I got Syntax error for this line.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadIshaq note that index 3 is position 4 within the array

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in javascript by using `forEach`:

```js
results = [];
outerarray.forEach(function(a) { 
  if (a[2]==="Type 4 Sheets") 
    results.push(a) 
});
```

`a` will be each array inside the `outerarray`

`results` should have all internal arrays that contains the given string in the 3rd. position.